# Submitting via curl in a bash script to sharepoint

Tags: json, bash, curl, sharepoint

I've been scratching my head for a couple of days on this one. Google-foo, sadly, isn't turning up much. I'd like to stay in bash if at all possible for portability

This works:

```
    node="$(curl -s --anyauth -u dom\\r-hah:haha -d '{"Filename":"0117-SCLP1-6230-0_E_H.mp4",
"MediaPath":"\/2016",
"SpotNumber":"0117-SCLP1-6230-0 E  H",
"SpotName":"TEST FOR TECH",
"Description":"TEST SPOT ONLY",
"ShipListPromoID":"467733"}' -H content-type:application/json -X POST https://somewebsite.com/fcp/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/FinishedSpots);
 echo "${node}"
```

This does not:

```
dslresults="$(php /usr/local/sbin/lookupupfrontspot.php "0117-SCLP1-6230-0_E_H.mp4")";
 echo "${dslresults}";
 node="$(curl -s --anyauth -u dom\\r-hah:haha -d '$dslresults' -H content-type:application/json -X POST https://somewebsite.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/FinishedSpots);
 echo "${node}"
```

Let me add that in the first example, I am copy and pasting the results of echo "${dslresults}" from the second example. So I'm guessing it's some kind of formatting error, but I can't seem to identify it.

Any obvious snafus I'm doing? (I'm sure there's tons)
  Thanks much.
      -N

Comment: Got it:  node="$(echo $dslresults | curl -s --anyauth -u dom\\r-hah:haha -d @- -H content-type:application/json -X POST https://somewebsite.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/FinishedSpots)"; echo "${node}"